# Change project default path in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration, ide

When I create a new project in my NetBeans 11.3 IDE the `/home/user/NetBeansProjects` project path is given by default for a project location. I need to change it to be default `/home/user/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects`. I don't want to change it every time when I create a new project.

The question is about java with Maven Application at least.

**edit**

My OS is Debian 10 with xfce.

Comment: [1] When creating your new Maven application, just click the **Browse...** button to the right of the **Project Location** field. Then navigate to the desired directory, which is `/home/user/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects` in your case. [2] That selection is sticky, and will  become the default directory for any new project created using the Project Wizard (**File > New Project...**) thereafter.

Comment: @skomisa This did not worked. I did this way, but not succeed. The old default path remained.